# How to make a computer DNS in local area network?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, lan

I am in my college and working on DNS. Whenever, I need to use network, I have to login using 10.2.0.10:8090. Now, some times it becomes tough to do so. For my own system, I know that we can make some changes to /etc/hosts and get the desired result:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Shahjahan
10.2.0.10:8090   login


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I want to make my computer a DNS server for the lan. How can I do so. I know I need to define zones and such things. Please link any answer or tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: Also see: [How can I set up a 'local' domain so that everyone on my local network can view a locally hosted site?](http://superuser.com/questions/410053/how-can-i-set-up-a-local-domain-so-that-everyone-on-my-local-network-can-view)

Answer (score 0):

[dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) is a light and simple DNS server (it also is a DHCP and TFTP server).  Once installed on a machine it will use that machine's `/etc/hosts` file as its name database (it can be configured to use a seperate file as well).

The only significant snag is that windows clients need a slight tweak to their network settings to function correctly, specifically their DNS settings need to be set to append a `.` to their queries.

Once installed you'll need to either advertise the DNS server by running your own DHCP server, reconfiguring the existing DHCP server (which I'm guessing isn't an option), or manually configuring clients to use the dnsmasq server for their primary DNS.