# How can I Host a website with a Domain name just within the Local Network?

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, xampp

I host a website on a local network with XAMPP. I usually access it with the IP address on another device.

How can I host my website on a domain like `website.local` ?

Comment: Use [multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) (mDNS). What you need to set it up is depends on the platform you’re running the webserver on (which you did not mention).

Comment: @StarCat I'm running Apache on windows

Comment: On what Operating System?

Comment: @StarCat windows

Answer (score 0):

The domainname does not matter. The other device must be able to resolve the name, so edit the /etc/hosts file on the other device and add a line like:

```
<wepserver-ip> <domain-name>
```

For example:

```
192.168.1.20   www.google.com
```

On Windows you will find the hosts file in %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc folder.

Comment: Already tried that, the website will be accessed by multiple devices. Some of them are mobile devices and sometimes new users will connect to the network. So that solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use multicast DNS (mDNS) for this purpose. To do that, you will need to set up mDNS on your computer. It seems to be a bit tricky to configure mDNS on Windows, and you might need to download Bonjour.

This question previously asked on SuperUser may provide some insights into how to solve your problem: [How can I set up a 'local' domain so that everyone on my local network can view a locally hosted site?](https://superuser.com/questions/410053/how-can-i-set-up-a-local-domain-so-that-everyone-on-my-local-network-can-view)

Alternatively, you can try building an actual DNS server. Many routers have support for DNS and you may be able to add entries to it. The specific method depends on your router.

Comment: I'll checkout Bonjour then.

Comment: Juan I've got no clue on setting up bonjour